# cuda out-of-core implementation using a circular buffer

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to do out-of-core between GPU memory and CPU memory. For example, I have blocks of data each is 1GB, and I need to process 1000 of such blocks in order, each is done by a kernel launch. Assume the processing must be done one by one, because the n'th kernel launch needs to use the result produced by the (n-1)'th kernel, which is stored in the (n-1)'th block, except the first kernel launch. So I'm thinking of using a circular buffer on GPU to store the most recent 5 blocks, and use events to synchronize between the data stream and the task stream. The data stream prepares the data and the task stream launches the kernels. The code is illustrated as the following.

```
const int N_CBUF = 5, N_TASK = 1000;

// Each pointer points to a data block of 1GB
float* d_cir_buf[N_CBUF];
float* h_data_blocks[N_TASK];

// The data stream for transfering data from host to device.
// The task stream for launching kernels to process the data.
cudaStream_t s_data, s_task;

// The data events for the completion of each data transfer.
// The task events for the completion of each kernel execution.
cudaEvent_t e_data[N_TASK], e_task[N_TASK];

// ... code for creating the streams and events.

for (int i = 0; i < N_TASK; i++) {
  // Data transfer should not overwritten the data needed by the kernels.
  if (i >= N_CBUF) {
    cudaStreamWaitEvent(s_data, e_task[i-N_CBUF+1]);
  }
  cudaMemcpyAsync(d_cir_buf[i % N_CBUF], h_data_blocks[i], ..., cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, s_data);
  cudaEventRecord(e_data[i], s_data);

  cudaStreamWaitEvent(s_task, e_data[i]);

  // Pass the current and the last data block to the kernel.
  my_kernel<<<..., s_task>>>(d_cir_buf[i % N_CBUF], 
    i == 0 ? 0 : d_cir_buf[(i+N_CBUF-1)%N_CBUF]);
  cudaEventRecord(e_task[i], s_task);
}
```

I'm wondering if this is even a valid idea, or is there anything completely wrong? Also, the CUDA programming guide mentioned that if there is memcpy from two different host memory address to the same device address, then there will be no concurrent execution, does this matter in my case? In particular, if the memory for `d_cir_buf` is allocated as a whole big block and then split into 5 pieces, would that count as "the same memory address in device", causing concurrency to fail? Also, in my case the (n+5)'th data transfer will go to the same address as the n'th data transfer, however, given the synchronization required, there won't be two such transfers to execute at the same time. So is this OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the feeling that your problem is best suited to double buffering:

- two streams
- upload data1 in stream1
- run kernel on data1 in stream1
- upload data2 in stream2
- run kernel on data2 in stream2

... And so on

Kernel in stream2 can overlap with data transfers in strezm 1 and vice versa

Comment: Thank you, double buffering is a special case of my program when setting `N_CBUF` to 2, but I need it to be at least 3 because each kernel launch needs to use 2 consecutive blocks. My question is, is this way of implementing double/triple/N-tuple buffering correct? Or is there any problem which will disable concurrency?

Comment: To my knowledge double buffering is the only option in case you can run one kernel at a time. Overlapping computation and memory transfers is the objective and so you can have the two kernels getting more than two elements/bloks, for sure. That's double buffering as well. The only very important thing is that you don't touch the queue blocks used by the kernel being run while preparing data for the next to come, in [this way](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#creation-and-destruction-streams)

Comment: I see, you are right, I didn't intend to let different kernels run at the same time in this case, but I missed the synchronization to prevent that from happening.